# Tcl: [file tempdir]

Tags: directory, tcl, temp

Somehow in [tcl 8.6](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm):

- `file tempdir` - is missing
- `file tempfile` - is present

Question: why there is no `tempdir` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `file tempdir` because there wasn't a sufficiently pressing need for someone to code it up, whereas temporary files are much more pressing (and harder to get right, especially across operating systems). You can always use tcllib as well as Tcl as they're under identical licenses; that library of Tcl-scripted packages provides a [fileutil](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html#26) package that has this command:

```
set dirname [fileutil::maketempdir]
```

which should be plenty adequate. (There's a bunch of options available to cover most needs.)

Comment: Yeah, it's not theoretically difficult, but it won't go in until we know where the patch is and have checked it out. I can't find a branch or issue that looks like an implementation (and I'm busy with other changes so I'm not writing it myself). **NO VAPOURWARE!**

Comment: I've been looking at this in more depth; the implementation very much isn't there (except on one platform, which has a limited internal version). Looks like I need to write it myself (especially as the one in tcllib has a few subtleties missed).

Comment: why is there need to have it in `native` form? why not  deliver more `standard tcl` features as `*.tm`, such as `/usr/lib/tcl8/8.6/http-2.8.12.tm`?

Answer (score 1):

A pattern without `fileutil` dependency:

```
proc ::util::tempdir {template} {
    close [file tempfile path $template]
    file delete $path
    file mkdir $path
    return $path
}
```

Comment: You were leaking a file handle; `file tempfile` opens the temporary file for you as well as (optionally) providing the filename.

Comment: works, thank you. `tcl` can make one astonished :-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: In fact, I got more surprises in python 2, where `print(foo)` is a statement, not a function call.

Answer (score 0):

What I did:

```
set workdir [exec mktemp -d]
```

Note: this depends on an external binary `mktemp`. I think this should work on anything UNIX-y.